# Error in Querying (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot do queries. I have pretty much set up everything correctly
[image]

Comment: You need to connect to the right database, now, you are querying the `master` database.

Comment: Apart from connecting to the correct database, you might well have done everything correctly. :) Unfortunately, that one incorrect thing is why your query isn't working.

Comment: You know the thing with IT? PRETTY MUCH CORRECTLY is NOT CORRECT. Either you do it correct, or you get an error.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have selected Database to be master. Select the appropriate Database where your table exists.
In this case, select `'sqlexpress'`, database